# What does "but she felt it all the way down" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, reading

A paragraph from [*Redemption Road: A Novel*](https://books.google.com/books?id=0ynECwAAQBAJ&pg=PA54&lpg=PA54&dq=%22contact+was+swift,+but+she+felt+it+all+the+way+down,+a+large+man+using+his+size%22&source=bl&ots=0D05qAaYj0&sig=fcKyJJy4zKqqzHRHFWeGClQ5JdA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit1tCxq5ffAhXaHzQIHRK0BNAQ6AEwAXoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22contact%20was%20swift%2C%20but%20she%20felt%20it%20all%20the%20way%20down%2C%20a%20large%20man%20using%20his%20size%22&f=false), by John Hart:

> People filed out. The big patrolman waited until the end and brushed Elizabeth with a shoulder as he passed. The contact was swift, but she felt it all the way down, a large man using his size. She watched him go.

What does "but she felt it all the way down" mean?

Comment: Normally you'd expect it to be stated what she felt it down. We just have to guess. Maybe it's her arm, or her whole body? I wouldn't bother guessing; I'd just put it down to poor writing.